# XOR-ing 2 bytes in assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86-16, xor, emu8086

So I'm given 2 numbers on 8 bits, let's call them *a* and *b*. I need the assembly program (emu8086 with registers on 16 bits) that performs some operations on them (which I think I can handle if I reach that point) **if** the first 3 bits are the same (so the most significant ones).

I'm new to assembly, but the most straightforward solution seems to be `XOR`, since `XOR` will give 0 for inputs which are identical (0 xor 0 = 0, 1 xor 1 = 0) and 1 for different inputs.

But how can I do that for 2 bytes? Is it possible to consider each of them an array and 'compare' them bit by bit and store the result of the `XOR` in some other register? And then how can I 'isolate' only the 3 most significant bits of this result?

Comment: Please show us your first code attempt.

Comment: XOR 8 bit values will perform an xor for each bit, returning the value at that bit position. so XOR 1nnnnnnnb with 0nnnnnnnb will have a 1 in the topmost bit. If you just want to have 3 bits set, you can use "AND" to mask them out (set all bits you want to 1, the others to 0) :e.g.  "010nnnnn AND 11100000" (top 3 bits 1) will return "01000000"

Comment: I simply did like that : MOV AH, a     MOV AL, b    XOR AH,AL

Comment: Oh, you're right, the XOR already takes them bit by bit. I just emulated them with the single-step thing and now the first half of the AX (so the AH) has the result of the XOR and the second part (AL) has the value of b.

Comment: Thank you ! I'll try the thing with the mask now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you're on the right track with XOR.  That lets you do it more efficiently than masking both inputs to feed a `cmp`.

```
mov   al, [a]
xor   al, [b]
test  al, 11100000B
```

will set ZF if the high 3 bits match, so you can `jz  high_bits_match` or whatever.  ZF will be cleared if any of the bits selected by the bitmask differ, because the XOR result will be non-zero there.

`test` sets flags according to the bitwise AND of its args, like the `and` instruction, but without writing either input operand.  (i.e. it's an AND instruction that throws away the result and just sets flags.)

If you do want a 0 / non-zero integer result, you can just use `and` instead of `test`

Comment: the Q was worded "first three bits - most significant", i.e. "first" from "right". While not common, I would follow rather the "most significant" part, i.e. `test al,11100000B`